# search and return key value pair based on a specific value

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary, hashmap, key-value

I am new in Angular and doing key value pair for the first time. I am trying to get the key value pair based on a particular value inside a nested key value map.  I have a nested JSON data format:

```
journey = {
"20180201": [{
        "journeyId": 1001,
        "Number": "001",
        "DriverName":"Alex",
        "Transporter": {
            "id": "T1",
            "number": "AN01001",
            "Company": "Tranzient"
        }
        "place": [{"id":001,"value":"Washington DC" }]
                  [{"id":002,"value":"Canberra"}]
    }]
    [{
       "journeyId": 1002,
        "Number": "001",
        "DriverName":"Tom",
        "Transporter": {
            "id": "T2",
            "number": "AN01002",
            "Company": "Trax"
        }
        "place": [{"id":002,"value":"Canberra" }]
                  [{"id":004,"value":"Vienna"}]
    }]
    [{
         "journeyId": 1003,
        "Number": "004",
        "DriverName":"Jack",
        "Transporter": {
            "id": "T3",
            "number": "AN01003",
            "Company": "Trax"
        }
        "place": [{"id":001,"value":"Washington DC" }]
                  [{"id":004,"value":"Vienna"}]
    }],
"20180211": [{
         "journeyId": 1004,
        "Number": "005",
        "DriverName":"Jack",
        "Transporter": {
            "id": "T3",
            "number": "AN01013",
            "Company": "Trax"
        }
        "place": [{"id":005,"value":"Bridgetown" }]
                  [{"id":006,"value":"Ottawa"}]
                  [{"id":004,"value":"Vienna"}]

    }]
    [{
       "journeyId": 1005,
        "Number": "005",
        "DriverName":"Jerry",
        "Transporter": {
            "id": "T3",
            "number": "AN01020",
            "Company": "Trax"
        }
        "place": [{"id":005,"value":"Bridgetown" }]
                  [{"id":006,"value":"Ottawa"}]
    }],
"20180301": [{
        "journeyId": 1006,
        "Number": "005",
        "DriverName":"demy",
        "Transporter": {
            "id": "T3",
            "number": "AN01003",
            "Company": "Trax"
        }
        "place": [{"id":005,"value":"Bridgetown" }]
                  [{"id":006,"value":"Ottawa"}]
    }]
```

};

I am trying to filter out the all the journey key value pairs which have its **place[value]=Vienna**.

My expected output should :

```
journey = {
    "20180201": 
        [{
           "journeyId": 1002,
            "Number": "001",
            "DriverName":"Tom",
            "Transporter": {
                "id": "T2",
                "number": "AN01002",
                "Company": "Trax"
            }
            "place": [{"id":002,"value":"Canberra" }]
                      [{"id":004,"value":"Vienna"}]
        }]
        [{
             "journeyId": 1003,
            "Number": "004",
            "DriverName":"Jack",
            "Transporter": {
                "id": "T3",
                "number": "AN01003",
                "Company": "Trax"
            }
            "place": [{"id":001,"value":"Washington DC" }]
                      [{"id":004,"value":"Vienna"}]
        }],
    "20180211": [{
             "journeyId": 1004,
            "Number": "005",
            "DriverName":"Jack",
            "Transporter": {
                "id": "T3",
                "number": "AN01013",
                "Company": "Trax"
            }
            "place": [{"id":005,"value":"Bridgetown" }]
                      [{"id":006,"value":"Ottawa"}]
                      [{"id":004,"value":"Vienna"}]

        }]

};
```

I am not finding out where do I start from .

Comment: Why you do not just loop that JSON? And inside loop (forEach e.g.) by condition if (jorney.place.value === Vienna) collect all data you wish

Comment: @Sh.Pavel inside the loop I need to return the date ("20180211") too which is not happening and instead giving me all the dates(since inside the loop)

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter your array with the filter() method from javascript.
https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_filter.asp.

Example:

```
// your array containing objects
var arr = [{
    id: 2,
    text: 'asdasdasd'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'mytext'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'mytext'
  }];
// filter array by property 'text' = 'mytext'
var filteredArray = arr.filter(function(item) {
  return item.text === 'mytext';
});
```

As result you'll have in `filteredArray` now:

```
[{
  id: 3,
  text: 'mytext'
},
{
  id: 1,
  text: 'mytext'
}]
```

Comment: But I have a lot of nested pair and array too inside. How does I loop through all the arrays-> key-value pair -> arrays -> key- value pair

Comment: You can for example filter a first array with journeys and then call the 'find()' method within the filter-method to only filter objects that contain a specific value:
`var filtered = arr.filter(function(journey) {
  return journey.place.find(function(place) {
    return place.value === 'Vienna';
  });
});`